# How to add new display in textbox without replacing the first input

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, chat, newline, messenger

Hi I am creating a chat like application. Can you kindly help me? 
When I am entering a new message the initial displayed message is getting replaced  :(

Please see my codes below:

```
Private Sub saveMessage()    

    FileName = Format(Now, "MMddyyyyhhmmss")
    Dim RecipientFile As String

    If CurrentRecipient = "Edward" Then
        RecipientFile = RecipientFolder & FileName & ".txt"
    ElseIf CurrentRecipient = "Criziel" Then
        RecipientFile = RecipientFolder & FileName & ".txt"
    ElseIf CurrentRecipient = "Jerome" Then
        RecipientFile = RecipientFile & FileName & ".txt"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim Writer As IO.StreamWriter
    Writer = New IO.StreamWriter(RecipientFile)
    Writer.Write(MainRichTextBox.Text)

    Writer.Close()

    ShowtextRichTextBox.Text = (User & " : ") & MainRichTextBox.Text
    MainRichTextBox.Clear()
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance ! :*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your below code is just assigning (replacing) the latest value to the Rich TextBox,

```
ShowtextRichTextBox.Text = (User & " : ") & MainRichTextBox.Text
```

Instead, you should append the text as below,

```
ShowtextRichTextBox.Text &= (User & " : ") & MainRichTextBox.Text
```

Also, you can try the inbuild method of RichTextBox to append the text like, `ShowtextRichTextBox.AppendText((User & " : ") & MainRichTextBox.Text)`

*Note*: When appending, you should also add newline before the new text like, `ShowtextRichTextBox.Text &= Environment.NewLine & (User & " : ") & MainRichTextBox.Text`.

Modified code,

```
Private Sub saveMessage()

    FileName = Format(Now, "MMddyyyyhhmmss")
    Dim RecipientFile As String

    If CurrentRecipient = "Edward" Then
        RecipientFile = RecipientFolder & FileName & ".txt"
    ElseIf CurrentRecipient = "Criziel" Then
        RecipientFile = RecipientFolder & FileName & ".txt"
    ElseIf CurrentRecipient = "Jerome" Then
        RecipientFile = RecipientFile & FileName & ".txt"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim Writer As IO.StreamWriter
    Writer = New IO.StreamWriter(RecipientFile)
    Writer.Write(MainRichTextBox.Text)

    Writer.Close()

    ShowtextRichTextBox.Text &= Environment.NewLine & (User & " : ") & MainRichTextBox.Text
    MainRichTextBox.Clear()
End Sub
```